# How to talk to the living?

Tags: town-of-salem

I understand that as a medium, you can talk to the dead to gain information, and when you are killed, you have one séance where you can talk to the players that are still alive.

However, I've not been able to do this. As you can only do this once, I assume you have to click a button somewhere or type it command in chat. But I've not been able to find much information about how to play as any of the roles, even on the wiki. So how do you talk to the living players once you have died?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the [wiki page](http://town-of-salem.wikia.com/wiki/Medium) on Mediums:

> When you are dead, you may **click the sun icon during the day phase** to "seance" a living person once.
>   The seance will take place during the night.
>   When performing a seance, the dead can not hear you, though you will still be able to hear them.

This is referring to the sun icon on the top left of the screen:

[image]